# routing in IOS simulator doesn't work when I use inside RouterOutlet

Tags: ios, angular, routes, nativescript, router-outlet

I have a question about some code:

In routing.ts I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: "fp", component: FirstPageComponent }
    ]},
  {
    path: 'ro',
    component: RouterOutletComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent },
      { path: 'forgotpass', component: ForgotPassComponent }
    ]},
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/app/fp", pathMatch: "full" },  
];
```

HomeComponent.html have

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

RouterOutletComponent.ts

```
export class RouterOutletComponent {
  constructor( public _page: Page) {
  }
  public ngOnInit() {
   this._page.actionBarHidden = true;
 }
}
```

RouterOutletComponent.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I am in LoginComponent, I want to navigate in SignUpComponent or in ForgotPassComponent. For navigate I use:

```
[nsRouterLink]="['/ro/signup']"
```

or
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

```
 public gotosignup() {
    this.router.navigate(['/ro/signup']);
}
```

In Android this navigate works very good, very fast. When I run in IOS simulator, this routing doesn't works? Why???

I try to remove from RouterOutletComponent and this work in IOS simulator. I try to use like below and work good.

```
[nsRouterLink]="['/signup']"
```

or
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

```
 public gotosignup() {
    this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
}
```

Can you share with me any idea, why? How to solution it inside RouterOutletComponent ??

Comment: May I ask, why you are using `router-outlet` over `page-router-outlet`. `Page` is valid only when you use `page-router-outlet`.

Comment: Because I want to remove ActionBar in /login, /signup, /forgotpass

Comment: Understood but why `router-outlet`, you still have to use `page-router-outlet`.

Comment: As Manoj said - use `page-router-outlet` and then you could hide the `ActionBar` explicitly while using the injected `Page` like done here https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L34-L36